# Is this a valid way to assign properties to an object?

Tags: javascript, oop, properties, this, self

Is this a valid way to assign properties to an object? I have an if/ else statement and I want it to determine what the properties of **p** and **i** are.

```
function game(){
    var self = this;

    this.determineDifficulty = function(){
        var difSet = document.getElementById("dif");
        var chosen = difSet.options[difSet.selectedIndex].value;

        if(chosen === "Easy"){
            var d = 0;
            self.p = 1;
            self.i = 1000;
        }else if(chosen === "Medium"){
            var d = 1;
            self.p = 0.1;
            self.i = 100;
        }else{
            var d = 2;
            self.p = 0.01;
            self.i = 10;
        }
        return d;
    }
}

var myGame = new game();
```

If I alert `myGame.p`, it gives me the correct value. But is this good practice? As I understand, if I want a variable that I can use in multiple methods - I should assign this as a property of the object. Another alternative would be to return this is a regular variable. If this correct?

Comment: It depends - anything you assign to `this` (or `self`, in your example) is publicly accessible, like you've shown with `myGame.p`. You can declare variables inside the `game` function that are "private" - meaning that anything inside the function can access/change them, but you can't get outside of `game`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `this` reference inside of `determineDifficulty` to do your object property assignment instead of using a copy variable.  Note that this works because you make `determineDifficulty` as a object property of game.  If you declared it as an inline function inside of 'game()' then `this` would refer to the inlined function, not to the game.

Note that it is, however, good practice to Capitalize all constructor functions.  So it should be `function Game()` not `function game()`

EDIT:

You can do as I said to assign property values directly to the object.  However, if you are setting `determineDifficulty` as a callback function, then `this` will not refer to the object you need.

```
//For Example:

function Obj() {
    this.foo = 5;
    this.set_foo = function() {this.foo = 10; }
}

var obj = new Obj();
alert(this.foo); //5
obj.set_foo();
alert(this.foo); //10

//The Following will not work
element.onclick = obj.set_foo;
```

When the element is clicked, `this` will refer to the element and not `obj`.

Comment: `this` refers to my inline function, so I need to make determineDifficulty a property? But it's a method, not a property? I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: `this.determineDifficulty = function() ...` gives your game objects a property called determineDifficulty whose value is the function on the right hand side of `=`.  During the execution of the function body of `myGame.determineDifficulty()` `this` will refer to myGame.